# Django-Tailwind not rebuilding after updating the template files

Tags: python, node.js, django, tailwind-css, django-tailwind

I did everything the instructions on the package website told me to; when I launch `python manage.py tailwind start`, it does indeed rebuild the stylesheets and add any new classes, but the issue is, after that, it just doesn't do anything when I add new classes in my templates. I'm not exactly sure what could be the issue with it, as I set everything up like the instruction said. All configs should be the same, and, I think, in the content config in tailwind.config.js, this is the line that's supposed to detect all of my templates:

`'../../**/templates/**/*.html'`

(this file is in `[project_name]/theme/static_src/tailwind.config.js`, my templates are in `[project_name]/[app_name]/templates/[app_name]/[template_name].html`, so I think it should check out). And the terminal window I'm running this from in VS Code is at the project root directory too (with manage.py file)

Actually, from what I've found out, it doesn't seem to detect changes pretty much anywhere, even in its own template files.

Also, after fiddling around with it for a bit and googling some more, the only thing I managed to find that was looking more or less like it was going in the right direction was to add `mode: 'jit'` to the module.exports in the config as said in the official docs, but that didn't help much either.

Node.js version: `18.16.0` npm version: `9.5.1`

**EDIT**: I just realized that, if it does build classes after restarting, then there's no problem with the content paths, for anyone who manages to stumble across this post. So, then I'm still kind of just stuck since the installation and usage instructions of the Django-Tailwind package don't mention needing anything else to get the JIT mode working (and shouldn't it be on by default in new Tailwind versions anyway?)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this as well, I've been able to solve this by changing the `package.json` file.

Set the environment variable `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=1` in the `dev` scripts.

```
"scripts" : {
   ...
   "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=1 tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w",
}
```

It should then start rebuilding if you change the classes in your template.

Comment: for me it does rebuild in the terminal but i still don't see the changes